# Using common code in different projects where core types are are different in c++ using templates

Tags: c++, templates, embedded

I am working on a couple of projects which include common code. The projects are running using different cores with the following differences:

```
typedef long long i64;
// typedef unsigned long long u64; // In project A
// typedef unsigned long u64;      // In project B
typedef int i32;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef short i16;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef char i8;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef void* Data;
// typedef u32 ptr;                // 32b pointer in project A
// typedef u64 ptr;                // 64b pointer in project B
```

But of course, I want to support new cores in the future with different configuration.

I am no OOO expert, so I see the following ways to handle this:

1) Create 2 copies of "ProjDefs.h" and include it from everywhere in the project (in project A "ProjDefs.h" will have different content  than project B). This is I believe an incorrect way (but this is what everyone in my department is doing).

2) Have every class to inherit from "Object.h" which will enforce those specific types and have the following code:

```
template <typename Core>
class EV_Object{
    typename Core::I64 I64;
    typename Core::U64 U64;
    typename Core::I64 I32;
    typename Core::I64 U32;
    typename Core::I64 I16;
    typename Core::I64 U16;
    typename Core::I64 I8;
    typename Core::I64 U8;
    typename Core::Ptr Ptr;
};
```

Have every class inherit from it, thus receiving the correct types definitions.
The problem is:

A) Every class needs to inherit from it.

B) Because this is a template I will not be able to use source files (only headers).

Again, I am far from a c++ expert, but this is also feels incorrect.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ofer

Comment: why do you think 1) is incorrect?

Comment: Maybe you want to switch to use the standard types instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Comment: btw between the lines i read that you assume c++ expert == OO expert, this is not quite correct, c++ is a multiparadigm language and if you want you can use no OO at all (and it wouldnt necessarily be bad c++). Next, if 1) is a convention that is follwed by your team I dont see too much bad about it, while having each object inherit from some `Object` is a complete no-go imho

Comment: Yes, a simple `#include <stdint.h>` solves this problem without coming up with yet another set of typedefs that cause repeated problems in C++ code (which is very picky about types and what things are typedef'd from) and collide with other "poorly" written 3rd party code.

Comment: Keep the platform datatype glue down at a basic level, probably in a target unique directly selected by your build target logic; then you can share it with not only non-OO C++ modules but any C code you may need to make use of.

Answer (score 1):

What you absolutely should do, is to drop your "local garage standard" types and use `stdint.h` instead. Period.

Yes, you'll need to change your whole program - blame the person who decided to cook up their own type standard in the first place.

As for pointers, you shouldn't be hiding those behind typedefs anyway. If the size of the pointers themselves matters, that's code smell. For the very rare case where pointer sizes do matter, use `sizeof` instead of relying on typedefs.